# A Sequence That Keeps Changing?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence, sequence

So I get this special sequence of "items" as the following:

> 2 1 3 4 7 8 2 5 2 3 9

But look! If I put some numbers (randomly) in front of the sequence:

> **3** **4** 2 1 3 4 7 8 2 5 2 3 **8**

And yeah! It's changed! ... Wait... The sequence is oddly shuffled now... Oh! And longer?!

> 3 4 2 1 **7** 4 **3** 8 2 5 **8** 3 **2** **3** **6**

***So... Can you guess what is my sequence right now?***

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So... Can you guess what is my sequence right now?

> 2 3 3 5 4 2 2 8 5 3
>   as this is the count of letters in the words on the line above.

Comment: 2 4 2 3 5 2 7 2 3 5 2 3 4 5

Comment: Correct, very well done! :) (And no, don't continue this sequence again lol.)